# Google Drive Download API IN php

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

```
$drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$content = $drive_service->files->export($file_id, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media' ));
```

I am using API version 1, if there is API v1 download file code then please give me link. API v2 of drive is not working so please.

[image]

Comment: screen shot is attached in which export function says not a function of google drive

Answer (score 0):

### Instruction to Integrate Google Drive API

Download the `client_secret.json` from the Google Drive API Dashboard. Once you have it store it somewhere you can access. Then use the composer to install the [Google Client PHP Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/) from google official github repository for Google Drive Api. It's still in beta but works. I have tested it myself.

Have below code snippet in your `composer.json` then run `composer update`.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
}
```

After you have google/apiclient in vendor directory, include it in your workflow.

#### Sample Code Snippet

Below is the sample code snippet which I used lately in one of my project. You can tweak it to suit to your need. I borrowed this code snippet from the google official github repo. [Google API PHP Client Examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples)

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$credentialPath = 'creds/accesstoken.json';

$authCode = $_GET['code'] ?: null ;

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('Drive API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(implode(' ', [Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE]));
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

if (is_null($authCode)) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
} else {
    if (file_exists($credentialPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialPath), true);
    } else {
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = json_encode($accessToken);

        file_put_contents($credentialPath, json_encode($accessToken));

        print 'Token stored successfully';
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        print $client->getRefreshToken();

        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

        $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();

        file_put_contents($credentialPath, json_encode($accessToken));

        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        print_r($accessToken);
    }
}
```

#### Suggestion

Try to study the code given, and once you know the lifecycle of this script you can easily integrate `Google Drive API` to any framework, script. You don't have to rely on third-party services. Though sometime that is the desired thing to do. Let us know if this script works for you or not.

Comment: irrelevant answer..! but thanks I got by myself solution..!

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the solution. You can post your solution and mark it as answered. It will be helpful to people with similar problems.